# Make ScrollView smaller when snackbar appears

Tags: android, android-design-library, android-snackbar

I just started using Snackbar in my android app and I cannot make it make ScrollView smaller to that it doesn't cover anything inside of the ScrollView.

This is my activity's xml layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/container"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorBackground"
    tools:context="com.example.MainActivity">

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            [LOT OF ELEMENTS IN HERE]

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

I tried a lot of solutions on StackOverflow, but nothing has worked for me yet.

Comment: what do you mean to make your scrollView smaller?

Comment: Well, normally it’s height is set to match_parent, but when the snackbar appears I want it to be smaller by the height of snackbar

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So, I found a solution to my problem, this is the solution.
I have replaced `ConstraintLayout` with `android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout` in my activity's layout xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorBackground"
    tools:context="com.example.MainActivity">

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_behavior="com.example.DecreaseHeightBehavior">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            [ELEMENTS HERE]

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

And I have created a class DecreaseHeightBehavior, which looks like this:

```
package com.example;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.annotation.Keep;
import android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import static android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;

@Keep
public class DecreaseHeightBehavior extends CoordinatorLayout.Behavior<View>{
    public DecreaseHeightBehavior(){
        super();
    }

    public DecreaseHeightBehavior(Context context, AttributeSet attrs){
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean layoutDependsOn(CoordinatorLayout parent, View child, View dependency){
        return dependency instanceof Snackbar.SnackbarLayout;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onDependentViewChanged(CoordinatorLayout parent, View child, View dependency){
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams = child.getLayoutParams();
        layoutParams.height = parent.getHeight() - dependency.getHeight();
        child.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDependentViewRemoved(CoordinatorLayout parent, View child, View dependency){
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams = child.getLayoutParams();
        layoutParams.height = MATCH_PARENT;
        child.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
    }
}
```

This worked for me, but this solution doesn't animate the height of the ScrollView.

Comment: glad you followed my recommendation to use CoordinatorLayout.

Comment: maybe you should accept my reply instead to do one yourself after all I recommended you Coordinator layout, and/or at least you could upvote me

Answer (score 7):

My guess is that the best solution for you would be to implement a `CoordinatorLayout` as specified in this [page](https://lab.getbase.com/introduction-to-coordinator-layout-on-android/), if you see the GIF format in the link, you can see the animation of how the Floating Botton raises when SnackBar is triggered, try to substitute instead of the Floating Button of the tutorial the ScrollView element, I guess could work(ScrollView should be on top of the other attributes anyway..)

If does not work
possibly you want to extend ScrollView and override the methods you need as explained in the google [official](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components.html) documentation, this should always work, but you need to work a bit more.One of the two solutions should possibly make the trick.

Comment: Sadly I wasn't able to make that work, my app always crashes on showing snackbar now.
I have replaced my `ConstraintLayout` with `android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout` and added `app:layout_behavior="sk.tuke.smart.makac.utils.FloatingActionButtonBehavior"` to my `ScrollView`.

Comment: It won’t even print anything in log, but I found a solution to my problem and I will post it tomorrow

Comment: looking forward, gave you an upvote cause I learned something:)